# Pass an object to a view from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to pass a set of rows from a controller to a view:

```
$items = Items::where('group', '=', $group);
return view('listing', [
    "group" => $group,
    "exists" => $items->exists(),
    "items" => $items->get(),
]);
```

And in my view:

```
@if (!$exists)
    Nothing
@else
<ul id="items">
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <li>
        {{ $item->user }}: {{ $item->content }}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

The view will only return 1 item though. The length of $items is 1. If I `count($items)` in the controller, I get the expected number of items.

How can I pass an object to my view from a controller?

---

## My final solution:

Controller

```
$items = Items::where('group', '=', $group);
return view('listing', [
    "group" => $group,
    "items" => $items->get(),
    "exists" => $items->exists(), // Important! Has to go after!
]);
```

And in my view:

```
@if (!$exists)
    Nothing
@else
<ul id="items">
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <li>
        {{ $item->user }}: {{ $item->content }}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

Comment: @ChainList `$items->count()` gives me 1 in the view, 4 (expected) in the controller

Comment: @ChainList Laravel's Collection implements Countable, so passing a Collection to the `count()` method will actually return the number of items.

Comment: @Streetlamp What do you get if you `dd($items)` in the view vs in the controller?

Comment: the problem not in the `count()` method but in the items passed he gets one item all the time even if there is 10 items i am right ??

Comment: @patricus I just saw that. My bad. I edited my answer. How can i go wrong like that ?
+Streetlamp, what does contains $group ? A string ? An object ?

Comment: @patricus `dd($items)` gives me four items in the controller, only one in the view.

Comment: @ChainList `$group` is a string @Maraboc, correct

Comment: @Streetlamp were they both Collection objects?

Comment: @Streetlamp I figured out what the actual issue is and posted an answer, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the call to `exists()` before the call to `get()`. The call to `exists()` is modifying your query builder to add a `limit(1)` to it. Therefore, when you call `get()` after `exists()`, the query builder still has the `limit(1)` attached.

Your updated solution works because you removed the call to `exists()`.

However, the call to `get()` should still be done in the Controller. The view should only be passed the collection of objects, not the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put get() at the end it will work.

```
$items = Items::where('group', '=', $group)->get();
```

You are just pulling back the model object and not the data. That is why the count is 1 when you are expecting 4.

**Edited per comment**

I think the get where you have it might be causing some funkiness.

```
$items = Items::where('group', '=', $group)->get();
return view('listing', [
    "group" => $group,
    "items" => $items,
]);


@if (!$items->exists())
    Nothing
@else
<ul id="items">
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <li>
        {{ $item->user }}: {{ $item->content }}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

You might put a `dd($items->toArray());` after you query Items to see what you get.

Comment: Wouldn't that be running `->get()` twice though? The view would receive `$items` as `Items::()->get()->get();`

Comment: @whoacowboy Collections don't have an `exists()` method. I think you're looking for `@if ($items->count() == 0)`.

Comment: @whoacowboy I had that before and it did not work, as per @patricus I moved from `exists()` to `count() == 0` and it works now. Thank you both!